# check if the element is present in list or not

Tags: python

I have a list
hi

```
w = ['4KUI_YLR242C.pdb', '2CQA_CGI-52.pdb', '4G4S_YFR051C.pdb']


if '4KUI' in w:
    print "got !!"
```

But, I am not able to print 'got'. how can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

This is because there is no element in `w` that is `'4KUI'`. There certainly is one that starts that way, though.
I think this is what you're looking for:

```
w = ['4KUI_YLR242C.pdb', '2CQA_CGI-52.pdb', '4G4S_YFR051C.pdb']
if any(i.startswith("4KUI") for i in w):
    print "got !!"
```

Comment: Or, more generically, `"4KUI" in i`

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing the whole string there.
you need to do something like

```
for string in w:
    if '4kui' in string:
        print "got!!"
```

Comment: Bit confusing to use `string` as your variable name given that there's a python module with that name. Would be better to use something else.

Comment: Well i did it mainly for clarity of what was going on, not for actual use.

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

entries = ['Glasgow', 'Edinburgh', 'Scotland', 'Dundee']

if [entry for entry in entries if entry.startswith('Dun')]:
        print "Found entry for Dundee"
```

**Execution**

> python example.py

Comment: While this works, @inspectorG4dget's implementation using the `any` keyword is far more readable.

Answer (score 0):

In this context "in" is determining whether '4KUI' is the value of one of the elements in your list. What you want is to see if '4KUI' is contained within one of the elements in your list. Try this:

```
w = ['4KUI_YLR242C.pdb', '2CQA_CGI-52.pdb', '4G4S_YFR051C.pdb']

for f in w:
  if '4KUI' in f:
    print "got !!"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
w = ['4KUI_YLR242C.pdb', '2CQA_CGI-52.pdb', '4G4S_YFR051C.pdb']

for item in w:
        if "4KUI" in item:
                print "got !!"
```